# Why is Roman Mythology so similar to Greek Mythology or vice versa?

Tags: greek, roman

It is weird to see two different mythologies so closely related to each other. Roman mythology seems to have some Greek mythology and vice versa. For example:

> Greek - Zeus, Roman - Jupiter

Two of the same gods with different names. Much of the two mythologies are closely related to each other and it can be confusing to know which is which. Why are the two mythologies so closely related to each other and what is the major thing that makes them two different mythologies?

Comment: Related: [When and how did the Greek mythos transfer to the Romans?](http://mythology.stackexchange.com/q/110/)

Comment: No really... Mine is about why they are so similar

Comment: Eh? That's exactly what the other question is asking about.

Comment: You'd expect them to be similar considering they are descended from a common religion.

Comment: **I think you have the privilege of asking the first duplicate question on the Mythology Exchange! Congrats!! Have an upvote**

Comment: @Daft Wait, what?! We're rewarding a lack of research effort?

Comment: @fredsbend lol, yep! Is your world crumbling?

Answer (score -1):

Romans had little mythology of their own when they occupied Greece. One of the many aspects they were lacking cultural wise that they borrowed from Greece. Thus they inherited many (or the lot) of ancient greek mythology which led to their existing Gods getting many of the characteristics of the Ancient greek ones.